# Javascript : ask an explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, explain

here's the full code:

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 

  // we use the regex match function which searches the string for the
  // pattern and returns an array of strings it finds
  // in our case the pattern we define below returns words with
  // only the characters a through z and 0 through 9, stripping away punctuation
  // e.g. "hello$% ##all" becomes [hello, all]
  var arr = sen.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi);

  // the array sort function takes a function as a parameter
  // which is used to compare each element in the array to the
  // next element in the array
  var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  });

  // this array now contains all the words in the original
  // string but in order from longest to shortest length
  // so we simply return the first element
  return sorted[0];

}LongestWord("the $$$longest# word is coderbyte");
```

but i just need someone to explain only this part  :

```
var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  });
```

I do understand about how function and sort works, but it kinda mixed and my brain crashed.
and also can you **give me** another **simple alternative** to solve this problem >> the longest word, what in my using `if-else` and comparing ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: So what's the problem? You just don't understand something? And you want us to give you an alternative using an if/else structure?...

Comment: @chazsolo no, i just need someone to explain that part, the rest is not that important ... if u want to gimme another alternative for my new knowledge is very pleasure for me.

Comment: You should read the API through the link Liam provided. It's just a comparator function checking the length property for each comparison.

Answer (score 0):

For the `sort()` function you can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

For an simpler alternative see the following code

```js
function LongestWord(sen) {
  let longest = "";
  sen.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi).forEach(function(word) {
    if (word.length > longest.length)
      longest = word;
  })
  return longest;
}
console.log(LongestWord("the $$$longest# word is coderbyte"));
```

Comment: Your alternative doesn't supply the same output as the given function the question.

Comment: @chazsolo why ? The function is supposed to return the longest word. That is what my function is also doing

Comment: The code in the question strips non-alphanumeric characters off each word, yours does not. All I'm saying is the output is different. OP's example longest word is "coderbyte", but yours returns "$$$longest#". Not saying your answer is _wrong_, but it isn't the same.